# How to generate all dates for a date range extracted from two date columns in SQL

Tags: sql, date-range

I have a table TEMP1 as :

```
Parameter   Val From         To
a           1   8/1/2018    8/5/2018
b           2   8/4/2018    8/8/2018
c           3   8/8/2018    8/13/2018
```

and i need the output like below:

```
Parameter   Date    Val
a   8/1/2018    1
a   8/2/2018    1
a   8/3/2018    1
a   8/4/2018    1
a   8/5/2018    1
b   8/4/2018    2
b   8/5/2018    2
b   8/6/2018    2
b   8/7/2018    2
b   8/8/2018    2
c   8/8/2018    3
c   8/9/2018    3
c   8/10/2018   3
c   8/11/2018   3
c   8/12/2018   3
c   8/13/2018   3
```

using SQL.

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: I am connecting to SQL using a spark connection

Comment: ok but which sql you connect definitely that is mysql or mssql or like that something

Comment: I am connecting to a mysql connection

Comment: @Dgstah When 6 people take the time to help you with an answer, it would be polite to accept one of them, or at least comment on why this is not what you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the select below to get the dates, join in your TEMP1 table to get the values you want.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpDates(  StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME  )

INSERT INTO #tmpDates (StartDate, EndDate)VALUES(   '2018-08-10', '2018-08-15')
GO

WITH myDates AS
(SELECT StartDate as aDate FROM #tmpDates AS td 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, aDate) AS aDate FROM myDates 
 INNER JOIN #tmpDates AS td ON myDates.aDate >= td.StartDate
 WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, aDate) <= td.EndDate)
SELECT aDate, 1 as aValue
FROM myDates
INNER JOIN (SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM #tmpDates AS td ) AS i ON 1=1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

DROP TABLE #tmpDates
```

Comment: Can we do it without hardcoding the dates? By selecting the date from the column itself? Since the actual dataset I am working is quite huge in size.

Comment: Could you not populate the dates first, in a separate statement?

Comment: Or just add that to the CTE, join in the table containing the dates.

Comment: I edited the answer according to your comments, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EindDate DATE
SET @StartDate = '1990-01-01'  -- << user input >> --
SET @EindDate  = '2018-12-31'  -- << user input >> --

IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#Date') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Date
IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#Date') IS NULL CREATE TABLE #Date (Date_ DATE)

INSERT INTO #Date VALUES (@StartDate)

WHILE @StartDate < @EindDate

BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Date
SELECT DATEADD (DD, 1, @StartDate) AS Date
SET @StartDate = DATEADD (DD, 1, @StartDate)
END;


SELECT * 
FROM #Date

CREATE TABLE #T (Parameter VARCHAR (10), VAL INT, [From] DATE, [To] Date)
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('a', 1, '20180801', '20180805')
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('b', 2, '20180804', '20180808')
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('c', 3, '20180808', '20180813')

SELECT D.Date_, T.Parameter, T.VAL 
FROM #Date AS D
INNER JOIN #T AS T ON D.Date_ >= T.[From] AND D.Date_ <= T.[To]
```

Comment: I have created a dates table for comparison. Tested this in MSSQL (tag was not provided at the time). Hopefully this will also work in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL (prior to V8) does not have support for recursive queries.  What you want to do is to join your table to a numbers table.  You can create one on the fly if it not too big:

```
select t.parameter, (t.from + interval n - 1 day) day as date,
       t.val
from temp1 t join
     (select 1 as n union all
      select 2 as n union all
      select 3 as n union all
      select 4 as n union all
      select 5 as n
     ) n
     on t.from + interval n - 1 day <= t.to;
```

I should note that you can also do this using a `Calendar` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a cartesian join:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/03a13/6

```
SELECT  s.*
FROM temp1 s, (
  select 1  'temp'
  union all
  select  2
  union all
  select  3 
  union all
  select  4 
  union all
  select  5 
) ss
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
WITH cte AS
 (SELECT Parameter,Val,From as dateval 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Parameter,Val,DATEADD(day, 1, dateval)
   FROM cte WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, dateval) <= To
 )
SELECT Parameter,Val,dateval
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below SQL Query for to get your result.
This was using Cursor and column names and alias may need to change as per your requirements.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @mindate date
DECLARE @maxdate date
DECLARE @parameter char(5)
DECLARE @value smallint
Declare @temp table( fromdate date, Parameter char(5),val smallint)
DECLARE cur_date CURSOR
STATIC FOR 
SELECT [from],[to], [parameter],[val] from temp1
OPEN cur_date
IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0
 BEGIN 
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur_date INTO @mindate,@maxdate,@parameter, @value
 WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO @temp
 SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @mindate, @maxdate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @mindate), @parameter as Parameter, @value  as Val 
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b

 FETCH NEXT FROM cur_date INTO @mindate,@maxdate,@parameter, @value
 END
END
CLOSE cur_date
DEALLOCATE cur_date
SELECT * FROM @temp
```